# Is it possible through an app to control other units on the wifi

Tags: android, ios, iphone, unit-testing, wifi

In my school we have this task that we have to build an online "product", not to actually code the product, but just describe it very well.
We are "making" an app, and therefor I would like to hear if you know.
If we imagine to iPhones connected to the same Wifi, is it possible to make an app there can get a list of units connected to the wifi, then choose the unit, and then send signals to that unit? I hope you understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have a look [here](http://androidexample.com/Scan_wifi_connections_or_Get_number_of_available_wifi_connections/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=90&aaid=114) and [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks). This is some simple tutorials. Yo can search more on your own:)